# Run multiple Gitlab CI jobs in parallel, but manually

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I would like two jobs to run in parallel in Gitlab CI but I want to launch them manually.
Basically I have multiple jobs needed to deploy my code to staging (build the server, build the frontend). I want to deploy to staging by clicking ONE button (hence making the jobs manual) but I want both of them to run at the same time in parallel (faster). I don't want both jobs to be manual because it displays two buttons in the Gitlab UI and someone could deploy only one part.

I tried creating a third, empty job, that would be manual, and have the real deploy jobs run automatically when the empty job has completed. However, even an empty job with just an “echo” takes > 30 seconds and I feel this is dumb. Here is my current solution that does not convince me:

```
start-release:
  stage: build-and-deploy-to-staging
  rules:
    - when: manual
  script:
    - echo "Starting staging deployment"

release-api-staging:
  stage: build-and-deploy-to-staging
  script:
    - "ENV_NAME=staging STEP=release_api release/deploy.sh"
  when: on_success
  needs:
    ["start-release-staging"]

release-frontend-staging:
  stage: build-and-deploy-to-staging
  script:
    - "ENV_NAME=staging STEP=release_frontend release/deploy.sh"
  when: on_success
  needs:
    ["start-release-staging"]
```

Do you have any idea how I could manage this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are the jobs you want to run in parallel in the same stage or different stages?

Comment: I can do both - I just want the 3 of them to run in parallel but be launched manually through 1 user action

Comment: Do you run your own runners, or are you using Gitlab.com with shared runners? If using your own, are you using the Docker executor?

Comment: Currently using gitlab.com shared runners! I could use my own runners if needed, but still, how would we manage this? Basically I want a single button through the gitlab.com UI to launch 3 jobs in parallel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To follow up from the comments, if you were running your own Runners, you can check the pull-policy for the Runner. There are a few values that tell the Runner what to do when trying to find a Docker image for the job.

The first option is `always`, which means don't look for any local images, and pull from the available repositories every time the Runner processes a job.

The second is `if-not-present`, which instructs the Runner to use a local image if one is present, otherwise pull from available repositories.

The last is `never`, which means to never pull from available repositories and only ever look locally. In this case, if an image isn't available locally, any job using that image will fail.

Knowing this, changing the pull policy to `if-not-present` or even `never` if you can maintain the available images on the Runner host(s), can greatly speed up your pipelines.

Another factor that can speed up a job that doesn't require any specific software is to use the smallest image possible that still meets any requirements. For your example `.yml` file, if you were to use an image such as `alpine`, pulling the image would be much faster as it is considerably smaller than other images (the image's description claims it's <5mb).

As for the pipeline itself, if you define both jobs in the same stage, with the same dependencies/needs, and mark them both as manual, there will be a single button above the Stage label on the Pipeline view to run all manual jobs in that stage, at the same time (as long as there are enough runners).

```yaml
job1:
  stage: x
  when: manual
  script:
    - ../do_something.sh

job2:
  stage: x
  when: manual
  ...
```

If all jobs in a stage are manual, you can start them all at once with the 'play' button for the Stage.

Otherwise, you could define it like you have in your question but the first job will need to be in a different stage. Per the docs, the `needs` keyword will only work if the "needed" jobs are in another stage.

```yaml
stages:
  - kickoff_build_and_deploy
  - build_and_deploy

kickoff_job:
  when: manual
  image: alpine:latest
  script:
    - echo '' > /dev/null

build_deploy1:
  needs: ['kickoff_job']
  script:
    - ./do_something.sh

build_deploy2:
  needs: ['kickoff_job']
  script:
    - ./do_something.sh
```

In this example, the build_deploy* jobs will run as soon as `kickoff_job` finishes and runners are available.

Comment: thanks a lot for this detailed answer! I didn't know about the pull policy settings, that's very interesting. Your solution is what I did, problem being the `kickoff_job` takes 40 seconds and I wanted to avoid that. But of course if I could manage to not pull the image each time it would be even faster I guess. Anyway thanks a lot, it's clear to me and I'll find the best solution for me right now.

Comment: Yea, if you can't get around pulling the image via pull policy, the next best option is to use the smalles possible image so the Network transfer is as fast as possible.

Comment: Second solution was perfect! Only adds about 11-12 seconds to overall build ... worth it. Thanks!